# Как разбить выполнение PHP-скрипта на части?

Tags: php, apache, timeout

Есть скрипт, который выполняет парсинг с сайта поставщика-партнера (все по согласованию). В настройках Apache у меня `Timeout` равен `300`. По завершению указанного времени работа скрипта завершается, высвечивается ошибка 500. Как разбить работу скрипта на несколько частей, по `300` на каждую?

Comment: Откуда ж мы знаем, не видя кода) Проверяйте в цикле периодически прошедшее время и в нужный момент сохраняйте промежуточные результаты куда-то.

Comment: @КириллМалышев какими функциями я могу воспользоваться для того, чтобы засекать время?

Comment: Здесь смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/q/10587323/7485582